# Como faço para imprimir a chave e o maior valor de um dicionário separadamente?

Tags: python

Fala galera, to com esse problema que preciso imprimir a chave e o valor de um dicionário separadamente dentro de um print, sendo que precisa ser o maior valor, alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

10. Faça um programa que receba o nome de um arquivo de entrada e outro de saída. O arquivo de entrada contém em cada linha o nome de uma cidade (ocupando 40 caracteres) e o seu número de habitantes. O programa deverá ler o arquivo de entrada e gerar um arquivo de saída onde aparece o nome da cidade mais populosa seguida pelo seu número de habitantes.

```
nome_arquivo1 = str(input('Digite o nome do primeiro arquivo: '))
nome_arquivo2 = str(input('Digite o nome do segundo arquivo: '))
adicionar = input('Deseja adicionar cidades no arquivo? ')
cidade = str(input('Digite o nome da cidade: '))
habitantes = input("Digite o número de habitantes que essa cidade possui: ")
mensagem = cidade + habitantes
dicionario = {}

with open(file=f'{nome_arquivo1}.txt', encoding='UTF-8', mode='w') as arquivo1:
    while True:
        if adicionar.lower() != 'não':
            mensagem = f'A cidade {cidade} possui {habitantes} habitantes \n'
            arquivo1.write(mensagem)
            novo_dado = {f'{cidade}': habitantes}
            dicionario.update(novo_dado)
            adicionar = input('Deseja adicionar mais cidades no arquivo? ')
            if adicionar.lower() == 'não':
                cidade = None
                habitantes = None
            else:
                cidade = str(input('Digite o nome da cidade: '))
                habitantes = input("Digite o número de habitantes que essa cidade possui: ")
                novo_dado = {f'{cidade}': habitantes}
                dicionario.update(novo_dado)
        else:
            print(dicionario)
            break

with open(file='segundo.txt', encoding='UTF-8', mode='r+') as arquivo2:
    for chave, valor in dicionario.items():
        arquivo2.write(f'A cidade {chave.get(max)} é a que possui mais habitantes, totalizando {max(valor)} '
                       f'habitantes \n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obter a chave de maior valor de um dicionário basta usar corretamente a função embutida [max()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#max)

```python
cidades = {
'Rio de Janeiro': 6747815,
'Brasília': 3055149,
'Salvador': 2886698,
'Fortaleza': 2686612,
'Belo Horizonte': 2521564,
'São Paulo': 12325232, 
'Manaus':   2219580,
'Curitiba': 1948626,
'Recife':   1653461,
'Goiânia': 1536097,
'Belém  Pará': 1499641,
'Porto Alegre': 1488252,
}

k = max(cidades, key=cidades.get)           #Obtem a chave cujo maior seja o valor.
v = cidades[k]                              #Obtem o valor da chave k.

print(f'{k} cidade com {v} habitantes')
#São Paulo cidade com 12325232 habitantes
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/q6Rt9z)</sup>

A função embutida `max()` devolve o maior item em um iterável. O parâmetro `key` especifica uma função de classificação de um argumento, para um dicionário a função `max()` itera por suas chaves usando a função referenciada no parâmetro `key` para obter o valor a ser classificado o que é interessante ser feito com a função [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) que retorna o valor para uma determinada chave.

## Bonus

Nunca caiam no engodo de inverter o dicionário para o classificar. Uma das principais características das  Tabelas de Hash é a univocidade das chave ou trocando em miúdos em um dicionários não há chaves duplicadas, se duas cidades possuírem o mesmo número de habitantes e você inverterem as chaves com os valores poderá haver perda de informações por sobrescrita. Veja exemplo:

```python
cidades ={
    'Duque de Caxias': 924624,                 #Duas com o mesmo valor.
    'Campo Grande'   : 924624
}

print({v:k for k,v in cidades.items()})        #Inverte a posição das chaves com os valores e imprime o resultado.
#{924624: 'Campo Grande'}                      #Sobrescrição das chaves, no caso de valores iguais ultimo valor inserido sobrescreve o anterior.
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/iQL6E6)</sup>

Comment: O problema descrito já existia antes de inverter o dicionário porque nomes de cidades não são únicos, e o algoritmo não trata valores duplicados, então inverter o dicionário não faz diferença porque nem os valores nem as chave são únicos. Se tem um problema fundamental é escolher esse tipo de dados para este fim, mas o OP decidiu fazer isto por alguma razão que a gente não tem como saber.

Answer (score -3):

### Atualização

Pela resposta do Augusto, eu aprendi que agora a função `max()` tem o argumento `key` que funciona como o `sort()` das listas. Então se tu usar o formato de dados adequado para o teu problema, que é uma lista de dicionários:

```py
nome_arquivo1 = str(input('Digite o nome do primeiro arquivo: '))
nome_arquivo2 = str(input('Digite o nome do segundo arquivo: '))
adicionar = input('Deseja adicionar cidades no arquivo? ')
cidade = str(input('Digite o nome da cidade: '))
habitantes = input("Digite o número de habitantes que essa cidade possui: ")
mensagem = cidade + habitantes

## Criando uma lista ao invés de um dicionário
cidades = list()

with open(file=f'{nome_arquivo1}.txt', encoding='UTF-8', mode='w') as arquivo1:
    while True:
        if adicionar.lower() != 'não':
            mensagem = f'A cidade {cidade} possui {habitantes} habitantes \n'
            arquivo1.write(mensagem)
            
            ## Criando um dicionário com chaves com o nome dos valores
            novo_dado = {'cidade': cidade, 'habitantes': habitantes}
            ## Atualizando a lista
            cidades.append(novo_dado)
            
            adicionar = input('Deseja adicionar mais cidades no arquivo? ')
            if adicionar.lower() == 'não':
                cidade = None
                habitantes = None
            else:
                cidade = str(input('Digite o nome da cidade: '))
                habitantes = input("Digite o número de habitantes que essa cidade possui: ")
                novo_dado = {'cidade': cidade, 'habitantes': habitantes}
                cidades.append(novo_dado)
        else:
            print(cidades)
            break

with open(file='segundo.txt', encoding='UTF-8', mode='r+') as arquivo2:
    maior_cidade = max(cidades, key = lambda cidade: cidade['habitantes'])
    arquivo2.write(f'A cidade {maior_cidade['cidade']} é a que possui mais habitantes, totalizando {maior_cidade['habitantes']} habitantes \n')
```

Exemplo:

```py
cidades = [
    {'cidade': 'Porto Alegre', 'habitantes': 12},
    {'cidade': 'Viamão', 'habitantes': 15},
    {'cidade': 'Alvorada', 'habitantes': 18},
    {'cidade': 'Canoas', 'habitantes': 9},
    {'cidade': 'Gravataí', 'habitantes': 6},
    {'cidade': 'Cachoeirinha', 'habitantes': 3},
]
maior_cidade = max(cidades, key = lambda cidade: cidade['habitantes'])
print(f"Cidade com mais habitantes é {maior_cidade['cidade']}, com {maior_cidade['habitantes']} habitantes.")
```

Resultado: **Cidade com mais habitantes é Alvorada, com 18 habitantes.**

Isto vai funcionar pra qualquer volume de dados porque uma lista é um iterável e as chaves de comparação estão bem definidas no tipo de dado apropriado.

---

### Resposta anterior, compatível com Python2 e Python3.3

Dicionários não são feitos pra buscar chave através do valor, o que tu quer fazer é complicado:

```py
with open(file=f'{nome_arquivo2}.txt', encoding='UTF-8', mode='r+') as arquivo2:
    habitantes = max(dicionario.values())
    cidade = list(dicionario.keys())[list(dicionario.values()).index(habitantes)]
    arquivo2.write(f'A cidade {cidade} é a que possui mais habitantes, totalizando {habitantes} habitantes \n')
```

Ou seja, passo a passo:

```py
## View com todos valores do dicionário
passo_um = dicionario.values()
## Maior número da view anterior
passo_dois = max(passo_um)
## Uma view não tem índice, então convertendo para uma lista, pra achar o índice da lista de valores do dicionário equivalente ao valor obtido anteriormente
passo_tres = list(dicionario.values())
## Acessando o índice da lista criada anteriormente pra encontrar qual é a posição da lista do valor obtido no passo dois
passo_quatro = passo_tres.index(passo_dois)
## Criando uma lista a partir da view das chaves do dicionário para acessar a posição encontrada no passo quatro
passo_cinco = list(dicionario.keys())
## O resultado final = encontrando a chave do maior valor do dicionário
passo_seis = passo_cinco[passo_quatro]
## Tudo junto
resultado = list(dicionario.keys())[list(dicionario.values()).index(max(dicionario.values()))]
```

Outra forma menos eficiente de iterar pelas chaves do dicionário a partir de valores:

```py
cidade, habitantes = [(chave, valor) for chave, valor in dicionario.items() if valor == max(dicionario.values())][0]
```

---

Uma solução bem melhor é inverter o dicionário. Se tu quer buscar por habitantes, isso tem que ser a chave, e não o valor: `novo_dado = {habitantes: f'{cidade}'}`

Aí fica mais fácil:

```py
with open(file=f'{nome_arquivo2}.txt', encoding='UTF-8', mode='r+') as arquivo2:
    habitantes = max(dicionario.keys())
    arquivo2.write(f'A cidade {dicionario[habitantes]} é a que possui mais habitantes, totalizando {habitantes} habitantes \n')
```

Comment: Maravilha, obg pela ajuda!

Comment: Resposta atualizada com outra abordagem mais adequada